# Importing line_profiler on my m1 max leads to segmentation fault

Tags: python, apple-m1, line-profiler

As I said in the title importing `line_profiler` leads to segmentation fault. I am running python 3.9.7/conda-forge on a macbook pro m1 max. Does anyone have any suggestions how I can resolve this?

```
% python 
Python 3.9.7 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Sep 29 2021, 19:24:02) 
[Clang 11.1.0 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import line_profiler
zsh: segmentation fault  python

% conda list | grep line_profiler
line_profiler             3.3.1            py39h4d2d688_1    conda-forge
```

Comment: https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler/issues/45 seems related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AKX Thanks that solved it.
Similar to [Seanlaw on github](https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler/issues/45#issuecomment-822091793) the following did it for me.

- conda remove line_profiler
- git clone https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler.git
- install requirements.txt
- python setup.py install

Comment: I didn't do "install requirements.txt" I followed the GitHub issue tracker recommendation and it worked! I had to upgrade my miniforge with brew before it would work.